# Why when i try to print a map content i get the adresses not the value ? in c++

Tags: c++, class, dictionary, object

I have a class `Servicii` that is empty and 2 classes `Car` and `Book`(I will use later for renting more types of services) that extends this class. Also I have another class `Person` .
After that I declared a map `std::map<Person*,Servicii*> servicii;` and this function:

```
template<class T>
void rentService(Person *p,T service)
{
    if (typeid(*service).name() == typeid(Car).name()) {
        if(p->checkDriverLicense()==true)
        {
            std::cout<<"Name:"<<p->getName()<<std::endl;
            servicii.insert(std::make_pair(p,service));
        }
    }
}
```

In main I've created some object :

```
 Car *c1=new Car("Skoda",150,true,"red",2014);
 Person *p1=new Person("Ale",22);
 rentService(p1,c1);
    print(servicii);
```

and the print function :

```
void print(std::map<Person*,Servicii*> m) {
    for(auto const &it: m) {
        std::cout << "[" << it.first << "," << it.second << "]" << std::endl;
    }
}
```

When I compile this is what it's printed :

```
Name:Ale
[0x1ba840,0x1ba4b8]
```

Why there in the map I have addresses?

Comment: Because that what pointers are  - addresses in memory.

Comment: You have a map of `Person*` and `Servicii*`. In other words, you have a map of pointers. If you want to see the name, you'll need to do `it.first->getName()`, similar to how you do in `rentService()`. What did you expect/want to be printed?

Comment: i have rentService(p1,c1) so in rentService p1 is p and c1 is T.So if the p have driver license,to insert this person(p1)  and his rented car(c1) in map .

Comment: Side note: `void print(std::map<Person*,Servicii*> m)` would be better as `void print(const std::map<Person*,Servicii*>& m)` to avoid copying the whole map before printing it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Direct answer:**

Since your map's key value pairs are pointers and the pointers are addresses which point to a address, when you are printing pointers you get a hexadecimal value which represent the address of the pointer

**Recommendation:**

- If you want to print customized information , what you can do is overload << operator for each class to print information you expect.

```
class Person {
public:
  ostream& operator<<(ostream& os, Person const& person) {
      return os << "I am " << person.m_name << " " << person.m_surname << endl;
  }

private:
  string m_name;
  string m_surname;
};
```

- If you store relatively lower size objects (you need to make a decision considering the hardware and software requirements)    just store objects instead of pointers in map.
- Easily maintainable way of pointers are smart pointer, Therefore give it a try to use them instead of raw pointers.

Comment: The member function `ostream& operator<<(ostream& os)` will make it possible to write (given `Person p`) things like `p << std::cout;` but not `std::cout << p;` which is what people and standard library algorithms will expect to work. The `Person` being streamed out should also be `const`.

Comment: Change as intended. Thank you!

Comment: You're welcome! It would need to be a `friend` function for that to work though.

Answer (score 4):

> Why there in the map i have adresses ???

Because that's what you stored in the map. The types that you specified for key and value are `Person*` and `Servicii*` respectively. Both of types are pointers. A pointer stores a memory address.

When you insert a pointer into a character stream, it will be printed as a hexadecimal number (except for pointer to char, which is treated differently).

> ```
> Car *c1=new Car("Skoda",150,true,"red",2014);
> ```

Don't use bare owning pointers. Either use smart pointers, or store as an element of a container. For example in this case, `std::map<Person,Servicii>` might be appropriate.

Comment: Sidenote: Using a pointer for a key in a `map` is almost never the right thing to do because you aren't mapping to a `Person` You're mapping to where the `Person` is. Can you imagine the fun that would be? A guy goes to the shop to pick up their car and is told, "No, Mr. Smith. We can't give you your car because you are standing two feet to the left of where you were when you dropped it off." And then the mechanic gives your car to Mr. Johnston because Johnston was standing in the right spot.

Answer (score 1):

You need to dereference the pointers:

```
void print(std::map<Person*,Servicii*> m) {
    for(auto const &it: m) {
        std::cout << "[" << *(it.first) << "," << *(it.second) << "]" << std::endl;
    }
}
```

Make sure that you've implemented `operator<<` for `Person` and `Servivii`.

Answer (score 1):

You are printing the pointer itself, which is an address.
what you need is the to dereference the pointer.
for example:

```
std::cout << it.first->getName() << "\n";
```